# WordPress - Javascript should run on the Server standalone

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to execute a Javascript every 5 min on a WordPress server. The idea is following:

- the Javascript file calls an api every 5 min via jquery.
- if the result call is succesfully I have to insert the data in the WordPress MySQL database via a PHP script.

I thought to add the reference to the Javascript file on the footer of every WordPress page. But it is wrong because every client would execute the call every 5min. And the script is not executed if there are not user on my WordPress.

Nodejs is not available on the Server. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways using that you can achieve your task.

1. Create a function and run as a cron job at server.
2. User **wp_schedule_event** method for more detail have a look https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to rewrite the javascript logic to php and run it using a cron that access the url. For running javascript in the browser and require a specific timing is error prone

Comment: I completely agree.

You cannot run Javascript on the server unless you are using something like Node.js in the backend. 
As you are running a Wordpress CMS it means your server is running PHP.

In your case Javascript is executed on the browser, so it means in the client. You can write a Javascript that runs the API call to the required Server and in the Server check that only call is running at a time. Again as commented too much error prone